# Saving new Date() in MongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6, meteor-collections

I try to store a date inside a mongodb collection:

```
const date = new Date();
const time = {
  date:  date,
  timestamp:  date.getTime(),
}
Collection.insert(time); // no schema
```

What is actually stored:

```
{ "_id" : "PmMCEANtvfBwNGApH", "date" : "2021-01-14T14:33:36.520Z", "timestamp" : 1610634816 }
```

What i would expect:

```
{ "_id" : "PmMCEANtvfBwNGApH", "date" : " ISODate("2021-01-14T14:33:36.520Z"), "timestamp" : 1610634816 }
```

What do i have to do, to achieve the second?

Comment: Is that your complete code? It would store as date.

Comment: @ForamSojitra I tried this, but then i got the same inside escaped double quotes

Comment: @Gibbs Yes it's the complete code

Comment: Are you sure? Because you have two time the same field name `date` and you miss a curling bracket `}` - the code should not work at all. Also using the same expression for field name and variable name seems not to be a smart idea.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Corrected, one is timestamp not date

Comment: do you use a IDE(robo 3t or nosql booster or ...) watching stored data?

Comment: Bud your code has still syntax error. Please provide a working piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Try this see if it works.

```
const date = new Date();
const fullDate = date.getFullYear().toString() +'-'+ (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '-' + date.getDate().toString();
console.log(new Date(fullDate));
```

Comment: Wow, this code gives me a `Exited from signal: SIGSEGV` in the second (const fulldate) line

Comment: ah it's because it's inside an async call

Comment: Sorry couldn't got you bro :/

Comment: i moved the code inside the main routine, and it's storing: `"date" : "2021-1-14"`

Comment: Store like this.
const time = {
      date:  new Date(fullDate),
      timestamp:  date.getTime(),

Comment: i did store it like this

Comment: Ok so this is a pastebin I have copied typescipt playground link thier you can get the code there.

https://pastebin.pl/view/3ad27961

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct because I runned and show result if you use `new Date()` for a field, the type is Date definitely like bellow photo
test other things, maybe type is correct in your db, but change when you fetch data
[image: result],

Comment: do you have applied a schema on your collection test? On Collections with a Schema, i also receive the correct ISODate Object. But in my case it's a schemaless collection.

Comment: No, do you store your data in collection with schema and mongoose?

Comment: Do you check your data type with a IDE?? Like robo3t

Comment: In this case no since i want to be more dynamic. So the Collection has no Schema attached.

Comment: We have Robo3t but we have issues connecting it to the server. I can use Meteor Mongo shell.

Comment: db.collectionName.find({ date: { $type: "date" } }) run this query, is result 0?